# Querying a Django model with ForeignKey and ManyToMany

Tags: django

I'm trying to teach myself Django and built a simple model for a teacher listing app. There are course levels (primary, secondary, high school, etc), courses, teachers and teacher-course memberships.

I want to fetch course levels & courses whose teachers are subscribed to a specific membership. Currently I'm doing following (obviously a very bad practice, but as DB is very small it's working properly):

```
course_levels = CourseLevel.objects.prefetch_related('course_set')

    # get mainpage teachers
    # TODO: This is inefficient, there must be some cool way of doing the same.
    for course_level in course_levels:
        for course in course_level.course_set.
            course.visible_teachers = course.teachers.filter(membership__type=Membership.TYPE_FRONT_PAGE)
```

And here is `models.py`

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class CourseLevel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    # courses can have levels
    level = models.ForeignKey(CourseLevel)
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    (TYPE_FRONT_PAGE, TYPE_COURSE_PAGE, TYPE_BASIC) = (1,2,3)

    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name='membership')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    MEMBERSHIP_TYPES = (
        (TYPE_FRONT_PAGE, _('Front Page')),         # Display users on the front page
        (TYPE_COURSE_PAGE, _('Course Page')),       # Display users on the front of course page
        (TYPE_BASIC, _('Basic Membership')),        # Display users after  
    )
    type = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=MEMBERSHIP_TYPES)
```

What's the better way to fetch these records, instead of iterating over courses and fetching related teachers in Django Query API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to add an attribute to your `Course` instances which lists the teachers keyed to the `Course` by the teacher's membership type?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it this exactly answers what you want but, is this the type of search you want to do?

```
Membership.objects.filter(type = 1, course__level__name = 'college')
```

I made two teachers, both who are type 1, both teach the class 'fun', and one who teaches 'fun' in 'college' and another who teaches 'fun' in 'grade'. Here are these outputs of a couple of searches:

```
>>> members = Membership.objects.filter(type=1)
>>> members
[<Membership: Membership object>, <Membership: Membership object>]
>>> members.filter(course__level__name='college')
[<Membership: Membership object>]
>>> Membership.objects.filter(type=1, course__level__name='college')
[<Membership: Membership object>]
```

Maybe this search is most like the one you were asking for:

```
>>> Membership.objects.filter(course__name='fun', type=1)
[<Membership: Membership object>, <Membership: Membership object>]
```